# how to open app info(settings) by using process id

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open app info page programmatically.

In which (force stop,uninstall,clear data,clear cache) options are available.I have running process id in list.

Now i am trying to open app info when i clicked on list item. I searched it a lot but could'nt find any topic related to it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `getAppNameFromPID(int PID)` to get the package name
2. Use `showInstalledAppDetails(String packageName)` to launch the App info/details settings page.

And those 2 methods should be created like so:

```
public void showInstalledAppDetails(String packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) { //this supports all API levels
        intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    } else {
        final String appPkgName = (apiLevel == 8 ? "pkg" : "com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
        intent.putExtra(appPkgName, packageName);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}

private String getAppName(int pID)
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List list = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
        try { 
            if(info.pid == pID) //see *NOTE: you might need to compare with info.pkgList
                return info.processName;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("getAppName", "Error>> :"+ e.toString());
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Each method seems to work individually, I would think this method would work for your needs.

*NOTE: This will not work if the process name is different from the package name (e.g. it is a service with a different package name).  You may need to tweak `getAppName` to compare with the strings[] in info.pkgList.  Let us know if this works.